# Grails/Hibernate: Null Pointer Exception on versioning

Tags: hibernate, orm, grails

Working with a legacy codebase in Grails.  Under some conditions (we're unclear exactly what) we get a mysterious NPE, stack trace as below, while doing a findBy.

So far we're sort of stymied; this appears in several fora for Hibernate but the responses seem to come down to "something is wrong with your schema."  It would be wonderful to find some additional detail to help us track the issue down.

**Update**

Thanks for the answer.  Yes, it's clear that at the point this NPE happens, `version` is `null`.  The trouble is that when we look at it in the code, it's *not* `null`.

We've begun to suspect there's a threading issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.next(LongType.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getNextVersion(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.listeners.SessionBinderJobListener.jobWasExecuted(SessionBinderJobListener.java:58)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersWasExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1910)
```

Comment: Of course, I don't have all the details but... how could a threading issue nullify something? A record with a null version column is totally excluded?

Comment: Oh, no, just the opposite: it's clear that at that point the version column *is* null.  It's just tough to figure out *why* because in the surrounding code it doesn't appear to be.  We have some confirmation of a threading issue, though, because we forced it to single thread and stopped getting the NPE.  Still don't understand the root cause, 'tho.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the trace:

- you or something do a `findBy`
- this [triggers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing) a `flush`
- the session contains a dirty object with a version field (of type `Long`) that needs to get updated
- Hibernate tries to get the next value for the version field for the update
- and that's where you get a NPE

The body of `org.hibernate.engine.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:131)` is:

```
public static Object increment(Object version, VersionType versionType, SessionImplementor session) {
    Object next = versionType.next( version, session ); // line 131
    if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) {
        log.trace(
                "Incrementing: " +
                versionType.toLoggableString( version, session.getFactory() ) +
                " to " +
                versionType.toLoggableString( next, session.getFactory() )
        );
    }
    return next;
}
```

And the body of `org.hibernate.type.LongType.next(LongType.java:79)` (which provides the implementation of the above `versionType.next`):

```
public Object next(Object current, SessionImplementor session) {
    return new Long( ( (Long) current ).longValue() + 1 ); // line 79
}
```

It seems clear that the `version` passed to `increment` is `null`.

I would thus look in the database for a record with a `NULL` value in its version column. Activating SQL logging might help to narrow down the search.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. This is the problem with old database records. You have added version column in your database table and @Version annotation in your VO and it works fine for the new objects, that were created after that chagne, however it fails for old objects - value in this column is null. The solution is to update all old object - their version column with 0 (or some different value depending on datatype). I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me. I added @Version for already existing objects, I had to update them all and set version = 0. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Version
@Column(name = "xxx")
private Integer xxx;
```

find @Version annotation in your VO and set this column a default value in database;

Comment: It turned out (it's been a long time) that this was actually a concurrency problem, where two threads were messing with the same entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
<version name="versionID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
  <column name="version" precision="10" scale="0"/>
</version>
```

try removing unsaved-value="null" or adding unsved-value="null"